# Adding an XML array in the user session

Tags: magento2, api, xml, session

I'm getting some data from an API. I want to save those data in my user session so that the API isn't called each time the page is reached.

1. First time: load API, save in session
2. After, load session

So this is my simple class :

```
class CadencierDataSession extends CustomerUserData
{

    public function getCadencier() {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCadencier();
    }

    public function setCadencier($cadencier) {
        $this->_customerSession->setCadencier($cadencier);
    }

    public function unsetCadencier() {
        $this->_customerSession->unsCadencier();
    }

}
```

This is how it's called :

```
$cadencierDataSession = new CadencierDataSession();
$cadencier = $cadencierDataSession->getCadencier();
$follow = "from session";
if($cadencier == null) {
  $follow = "from api";
  $cadencier = (new Cadencier())->get_cadencier($codeClient);
  $cadencierDataSession->setCadencier($cadencier);
  die('ok');
}
```

When I reach the **setCadencier** line, Magento throught this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement'
> is not allowed in
> /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:139 Stack trace:
> #0 /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(139): session_write_close() #1 [internal function]:
> Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->writeClose() #2 {main}
> thrown in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line
> 139

Who to avoid it? I'd like to keep the XML structure so that I don't have to recode this page.

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXMLElement returned from the API is an object, and you most likely want to get a string representation. Try the following:

```php
$cadencierDataSession = new CadencierDataSession();
$cadencier = $cadencierDataSession->getCadencier();
$follow = "from session";
if($cadencier == null) {
  $follow = "from api";
  $cadencier = (new Cadencier())->get_cadencier($codeClient);
  $cadencierDataSession->setCadencier($cadencier->asXML());
  die('ok');
}
```